# GUI for a new cmake

Tags: cmake

I installed Cmake 3.5 and I want to have a GUI for it, as I had before with cmake-qt-gui. But what was installed is only cmake itself. I expected cmake-gui to come with the source of cmake, maybe I just don't see it? If not, any chance getting a GUI for it? I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Cmake code for Linux comes with `cmake-gui`, but it is not built by default. One can open `bootstrap` file, scroll down and set:

```
cmake_bootstrap_qt_gui="1"
```

After that run `bootstrap`, `make` and `make install` again.